Filter SharePoint multiselect choice column via react query
I have a column in my SharePoint list, named "Catégorie", that is a multiple choice column, where I have multiple options "Option 1", "Second Option" etc.
How should I filter on that column if I want to check if "Second Option" was selected (among others)?
Actually my query is
const baseQuery = "IsDocument:True AND FileExtension:aspx AND Cat_x00e9_gorie:'Second Option'";

but it does not seem to filter anything, I have 0 items when filtered.

For a multi-select choice column, you can use the $filter query option with the substringof function. Here’s an example of how you might structure your query:
const query = https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YourListName')/items?$filter=substringof('Second Option', Catégorie);

This query checks if "Second Option" is part of the "Catégorie" field. Make sure to replace {site_url} with your actual SharePoint site URL and YourListName with the name of your list.
If you're still getting 0 items, ensure that:

The column name is correctly spelled and matches exactly with what is
in SharePoint.

The value "Second Option" is indeed present in the items of the list.



Your code does not seem to be a valid JavaScript
